Question about the requirements for the statement an ideal in a PID/(integral domain only) is maximal iff it is irreducible.
Background
The following is taken from Hungerford's Abstract algebra an Introduction and F Jarvis' Algebraic Number Theory
Exercise 1  Prove that an ideal $(p)$ in a PID (principal ideal domain) is maximal if and only if $p$ is irreducible.
Lemma Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $p\in R$.  if $(p)$ is maximal, then $p$ is irreducible.
Exercise 2 If $R$ is a principal ideal domain, show that the converse of the above lemma is also true.
Question
I  often see an exercise showing that an ideal is mxiamal iff it is irreducible in a principal ideal domain in the form expressed in Exercise 1.  I found in an algebraic number theory text, that the statement of Exercise 1, in one direction, it seems that in one direction of the statement, it holds true for a ring to be an integral domain, while in another direction, it need the stronger requirement to be a principal ideal domain.  What I want to know is why there is this difference.
Thank you in advance

An element $p$ is irreducible if and only if $(p)$ is maximal among principal ideals.

Simply because $(p)$ is max among all principal ideals is not equivalent to $(p)$ is max among all ideals, i.e. direction $(\Leftarrow)$ in the first $(!!\iff!!)$ in the standard proof in the dupe may fail in a non-PID. Generally you can find counterexamples by going through the proof line-by-line to find which step first fails.

@BillDubuque so is it better to express the statement ih both directions assuming the ring is a principal ideal domain then?

Doing so allows us to see how the proof follows immediately from the fundamental  (bidrectional) equivalence that "contains = divides" for principal ideals.

@BillDubuque sorry I don't understand what you mean by "immediately from the fundamental (bidrectional) equivalence that "contains = divides" for principal ideals"

I mean that it makes obvious the linked standard proof.
